# Bandwidth Calculation in WebRTC

Tags: angular

I am working on a project whereby I have to calculate the bandwidth of audio/video streams in webRTC. For this, I wish to use the "bytesReceived" and the "timestamp" for inbound-rtp and outbound-rtp to compute this value which I will later on display in a graph. Can someone explain to me how to use the enum  RTCStatsType to compute the bandwidth?

Comment: You need to filter events of some kind, most likely it will be either "inbound-rtp" for incoming bandwidth, either "outbound-rtp"

Comment: Can you please let me know how to about it? Thanks

Comment: ? sorry.........

Comment: If possible, an idea of how to compute the bandwidth with the "bytesReceived" and the "timestamp" for inbound-rtp and outbound-rtp audio/video stream. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Please read code here https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/

Comment: It should do what you need, I hope

Comment: I actually used a whole component which renders bandwidth graph from this code, when I was asked to display connection speed in real time

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use wireshark as a packet capture tool, you can filter the packets to just calculate the bitrate the bandwidth of the stream.

In adition to that, chrome://webrtc-internals/ shows the bandwidth statistics that you want to see, and it helps as a point of comparison too.